# Is there any way to take legal action on the inflammatory answers?

Tags: discussion, support, post-quality, new-users, user-accounts

For the last few days the site has been impregnated with inflammatory answers against Gods which are excessively abusive. Is there any way to take legal actions on them based on any IT act? If Yes, will HSE provide their IP or relevant information to case against them? Or is there any way SE itself provides a way to take legal actions on them?

Comment: I'm curious what "legal" actions you think could even be taken? At least in the US, where SE is based, saying negative things about religion, while unkind, isn't illegal.

Comment: @Catija In India there are punishments for the same. They can be punished if they are at least Indian if IP is found.

Comment: But, again... SE is not an Indian company...

Comment: @Catija whatever if their IP is found & they are Indians, content is sufficient. Now that is another matter if IP is not revealed.

Comment: @Catija You're missing the point. This site is about Hinduism. Anything offensive should be taken under consideration. It's same as posting a spam on StackOverflow. It's not about what a specific country takes on specific area. We can't simply ignore these spammers. yeah I agree that while we are on this site we must use our existing tools like flag or custom flag to handle these spammers. Flagging is as good as taking legal action with respect to our SE site.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Where did I say you shouldn't take action? Offensive stuff should be removed, that's obvious. Attempting **legal** action is absurd. When people on the internet are stupid idiots... get rid of them. There's no reason to try to find and punish them in real life, though.

Comment: @Rohit. While we are on SE, please use and follow what we have already. Don't even think of taking these issue outside SE.

Comment: Stack Exchange is based in the United States, and as such is subject to U.S. law, not the law of any other country. SE couldn't take legal action even if they wanted. The only obligation of Stack Exchange is to eliminate the rude posts. Another point to consider is that some of these trolls may be using VPNs to mask their identities. Also, having traveled to India myself, I can tell you that there are much fewer IP addresses in India than there are Internet users, and I've seen my non-VPN Internet connection routed through many different countries, even the U.S..

Comment: Now I get it. It's an April fool trick. No legal action or anything else. Isn't it?

Comment: You may contact [this user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/15008/jyoti-prakash-nayak).

Answer (score 14):

A lot of those chaps are trolls. Don't respond. Flag em, don't give them a response. They'll go away eventually.

*Practically* Its probably a lot of trouble, money and multiple jurisdictions. SE isn't going to share PII without a court order, and you'd basically need to ... well find a judge to give an order against someone who could be anywhere.

Much more effective to help the mods make them go away. Organise a posse, keep an eye on smoke detector feeds and make them go away as fast as possible.

Comment: More information about Charcoal is available on [our website](https://charcoal-se.org/), and you can always ask us questions in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq).